# Вызов оператора класса без создания его экземпляра (этого класса)

Tags: c++

Вот пример который правильно работает. Только не могу понять почему вызов **оператора ()** нормально отрабатывает без создания экземпляра класса.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct sq {
    int operator()(int x) const {
        return x * x;
    }
};

int main(){
    cout << sq()(5) << endl; // здесь должна быть синтаксическая ошибка. экземпляр класса пока не создан

    return 0;
}
```

разъясните в чем мое заблуждение.

---

обновил чтоб понятней было

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct sq {
    sq(){ cout << "constructor " << endl; }

    int operator()(int x) const {
        return x * x;
    }

    int print(int i){
        return i;
    }
};

int main(){
    cout << sq()(5) << endl; // правильно. создается временный объект
    cout << sq.print(10) << endl; // не правильно. здесь ошибка. объект не создается

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: измените на `sq().print(10)` ошибка должна пропасть

Comment: @Grundy действительно ошибка пропала. более менее стало понятно. насколько я понял что оператор () вызывает конструктор класса создавая временный объект. а оператор ()() это вызов оператора ().

Comment: ну вообще говоря оператора `()()` нет

Comment: ну да все правильно. спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sq()(5)
```

Здесь вызывается конструктор `sq()` и таким образом создается временный объект, для которого уже выполняется `operator()` с аргументом `5`. Ничего ошибочного тут не вижу.

Comment: смотрите мой обновленный ответ. из книги знаю что что бы использовать класс сначала нужно создать экземпляр класса и уже работать именно с ним.

Comment: @perfect, но, у вас же не класс, а структура

Comment: @Grundy структуры с классами ничем не отличаются кроме внутреннего доступа.